# where should I do Download my data in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to download the data from the web service, actually at the first time I just download it by the asynctask (background thread)and I execute it in the Oncreate method, this work fine.

but I also try to download in the ui thread in the oncreate method, so I just call the Httpclient directly in the oncreat method and this work fine and also faster,and the application doesn't fail when I press on the screen when it download the data.

I think the second method work fine because the application will not show the user interface until it finish the oncreate method.
Is this correct ? should I use the second method ?

the first method :

```
    oncreate(bundle saveinstance){
new Task.execute("url");
}
```

second method:

```
  oncreate (bundle saveinstance){
   makehttprequest("url")
}
```

THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: please add some code. So that one could get your question properly.

Comment: ok give me one minute ! i will update it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should not use the second method. On newer versions of Android doing any network processing in the UI thread will cause an exception to be thrown. Given the indeterminate amount of time a network call can take, doing those calls on the UI thread makes for a non-responsive UI that will open up to a blank screen for as long as it takes to complete the call.  Use the Async task and dhow a progress bar or a splash screen indicating to the user that you are downloading some content.

Comment: wow, ok but what if i use this lines of code:if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
  {
      StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
      StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
  } what do you think ?

Comment: Then you are overriding the default behavior so it will not throw the exception, but the exception is there for a reason. The reasons are as I stated - you will produce a UI that has indeterminate behavior based on your user's network speed.  This is a bad idea.  You are much better off downloading and caching the data from a previous run, then updating that data from the WebService in the AsyncThread. You should look at some of the Google IO Youtube videos that describe how to build responsive apps.